# How to match intercept on response

Tags: cypress

Here is an example of code
The first thing I do is intercept the request, then I want to wait until response will contain expected status in body. But the test is failing after default timeout - 30000ms with the error like this:

Timed out retrying after 30000ms: expected 'Running' to equal 'Completed'

So the test is failing because status is Running, and the expected is Completed. how to increase timeout in this case?

```js
 cy.intercept('GET', Cypress.config().baseUrl + 'api/scans/' + scanID).as('getStatus');

 cy.visit('/')

 cy.wait('@getStatus', {responseTimeout: 80000}).its('response.body.status')
   .should('eq', 'Completed')
```

Answer (score 4):

Continuing from Hiram's answer, if you don't know how many requests to wait for you can use a function to repeat the wait until the desired status arrives.

Of course, the "Completed" status may never arrive so you want to set a maximum number of request/responses to check (in lieu of the timeout).

To simulate your situation, I used a simple web site that makes three requests in 300ms intervals.

The response body has an id which happens to be the same as the parameter in the request, so we want to wait for `response.body.id === 3`.

**Simple app with 3 requests**

```html
<script>
  setTimeout(() => fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1'), 300)
  setTimeout(() => fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/2'), 600)
  setTimeout(() => fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/3'), 900)
</script>
```

**Test**

```js
it('waits for a particular response', () => {

  cy.visit('../app/intercept-last.html')

  cy.intercept('**/jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/*')
    .as('todos')

  function waitFor(alias, partialResponse, maxRequests, level = 0) {
    if (level === maxRequests) {
      throw `${maxRequests} requests exceeded`         // fail the test
    }
    cy.wait(alias).then(interception => {
      const isMatch = Cypress._.isMatch(interception.response, partialResponse)
      if (!isMatch) {
        waitFor(alias, partialResponse, maxRequests, level+1)
      }
    })
  }

  waitFor('@todos', { body: { id: 3 } }, 100)         // if no error, value has arrived
  cy.get('@todos.last')                               // now use get() instead of wait()
    .its('response.body.id').should('eq', 3)          
})
```

---

**Your test**

```js
cy.intercept('GET', Cypress.config().baseUrl + 'api/scans/' + scanID)
  .as('getStatus')

cy.visit('/')

  function waitFor(alias, partialResponse, maxRequests, level = 0) {
    if (level === maxRequests) {
      throw `${maxRequests} requests exceeded`        
    }
    cy.wait(alias).then(interception => {
      const isMatch = Cypress._.isMatch(interception.response, partialResponse)
      if (!isMatch) {
        waitFor(alias, partialResponse, maxRequests, level+1)
      }
    })
  }

const timeout = 80_000                            // timeout you want to apply 
const pollingRate = 500                           // rate at which app sends requests
const maxRequests = (timeout / pollingRate) + 10; // number of polls plus a few more

waitFor('@getStatus', { body: { status: 'Completed' } }, maxRequests) 
cy.get('@getStatus.last')     
  .its('response.body.status').should('eq', 'Completed')
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution for the same need with a polling process :

```js
    cy.intercept('GET', Cypress.config().baseUrl + 'api/scans/' + scanID).as('polling');
    const waitPolling = (res) => {
        const {response: {body: {status }}} = res;
        if (status !== 'Completed') {
            cy.wait('@polling').then(waitPolling);
        }
    }
    cy.wait('@polling').then(waitPolling);
```

Answer (score 0):

The response timeout isn't ignored, a response is getting caught within the timeout you gave, but it has a different property to the one you expected.

I suppose since the status can be 'Running' or 'Completed' that two responses are coming through. (Maybe also two requests)

I suggest you wait twice

```js
cy.wait('@getStatus', {responseTimeout: 80000})
  .its('response.body.status').should('eq', 'Running')
cy.wait('@getStatus', {responseTimeout: 80000})
  .its('response.body.status').should('eq', 'Completed')
```

If no luck with that, take a look at what is happening on the network tab.

Comment: Oh, I see, thanks. There are a lot of requests and responses, because API is triggered unless the status is Completed. I thought that setting this timeout will work in a way that will wait to expected response body property value.
Is there some mechanism to achieve that?