# How to get the last intercepted API only

Tags: cypress

I'm intercepting an API using `cy.intercept()`, and it appears that this API is being called two times so it gets intercepted two times, with different responses. I want to access the last intercepted one only. how can I do that?

```js
cy.intercept({
    url: `${Cypress.config().apiUrl}/ticket`,
    method: 'GET',
}).as('assignedTicketAPI')
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a recent question here [How to match intercept on response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68224453/cypress-responsetimeout-is-ignored-in-wait-function-with-alias), which is about tackling multiple requests on the same intercept.

You can wait twice on the same intercept alias, provided the route matching parameters are the same.

```js
cy.wait('@assignedTicketAPI')
cy.wait('@assignedTicketAPI').then(interception => {...
```

It's also possible to count requests in the intercept and assign a unique alias to the 2nd one caught - [Aliasing individual requests](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept#Aliasing-individual-requests)

```js
let intercepted = 0
cy.intercept({
  url: `${Cypress.config().apiUrl}/ticket`,
  method: 'GET',
}, (req) => {
  intercepted = intercepted + 1
  if (intercepted  === 2) {
    req.alias = 'assignedTicketAPI2'
  }
})

cy.wait('@assignedTicketAPI2').then(interception => {...
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution to this is set the middleware to false. This will ensure that you get the latest intercept, like this

cy.intercept({
url: `${Cypress.config().apiUrl}/ticket`,
method: 'GET',
{middleware: false }

}).as('assignedTicketAPI')

The documentation can be found here https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept#Interception-lifecycle

Comment: Why is that best? `{middleware: false}` is the default - what is your solution? Why does this work IYO?

Answer (score 0):

Middleware is not very well documented other than the link that I provided you with the diagram. But judging from the behaviour of intercept it seem that it defaults to true since by default when multiple requests are matched, waiting on an intercepted request yield the first response as shown in the diagram