# cy.intercept multiple matchers found. Is it possible to only wait for the last network matcher?

Tags: cypress, cypress-intercept

I have a network request to spy on which will always return multiple matchers. The first few matchers usually don't contain the data that I need to perform assertion and I would need to spy only the last matcher found.

Currently, I have to do a multiple `cy.wait()` before getting to the last matcher, which is not ideal. Just wondering if there's a better way to only wait on the last matcher?

All the interceptor network requests have the same "GET" and url pattern and the only difference is the response returned.

```
cy.intercept('GET', '**/gampad/ads?*').as('gam'); //this will usually return a few matchers
cy.wait('@gam'). //only want to spy on the last gam request
```

Answer (score 2):

**"the only difference is the response returned"** - if you have a specific response pattern to match against, there's an interesting idea here [How to match intercept on response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68235628/14783414)

It uses recursion to repeat `cy.wait('@gam')` until the correct response occurs.

```js
cy.intercept('GET', '**/gampad/ads?*').as('gam')

function waitFor(alias, partialResponse, maxRequests, level = 0) {
  if (level === maxRequests) {
    throw `${maxRequests} requests exceeded`         // fail the test
  }
  cy.wait(alias).then(interception => {
    const isMatch = Cypress._.isMatch(interception.response, partialResponse)
    if (!isMatch) {
      waitFor(alias, partialResponse, maxRequests, level+1)
    }
  })
}

waitFor('@gam', { body: { status: 'Completed' } }, 100) 
cy.get('@gam.last')                                        // get the last match
```

I guess there's a small possibility that between the call to `waitFor()` and `cy.get('@gam.last')` that the intercept catches another response.

This version returns the successful interception

```js
cy.intercept('GET', '**/gampad/ads?*').as('gam')

Cypress.Commands.add('waitFor', (alias, partialResponse, maxRequests, level = 0) => {
  if (level === maxRequests) {
    throw `${maxRequests} requests exceeded`
  }
  return cy.wait(alias)
    .then(interception => {
      const isMatch = Cypress._.isMatch(interception.response, partialResponse)
      if (isMatch) {
        return interception
      } else {
        return cy.waitFor(alias, partialResponse, maxRequests, level+1)
      }
    })
})

cy.waitFor('@gam', { body: { status: 'Completed' } }, 100)
  .its('response.body.status')
  .should('eq', 'Completed')
```

Answer (score 0):

`cy.wait()` waits for the requests in the order they are received, as you've noticed. However, using `.all`, this should work:

```
// use .all get a list of all requests then select the last one
cy.get('@gam.all').then(matches => Cypress._.last(matches))
.should(...)
```

Consider that it may not make sense to "wait for only the last request" in some situations, since you will not be able to know when the last request is made, until it is made.

Comment: `cy.wait('@gam.all')` should be `cy.get('@gam.all')`. The first throws `cy.wait() could not find a registered alias for: @gam.all. Available aliases are: gam.`